# java unmarshall different types

Tags: java, unmarshalling

I'm using a unmarshall method in Java, but I want to use different types in the method. How can I fix this. I would like to use an URL or a local XML-file.

File:

```
    public List<Order> readOrders() throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(OrderConfig.class);

    OrderConfig orderConfig = (OrderConfig) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
            OrderConfigReader.class.getResource("//filename"));
    return orderConfig.getItems();
    }
```

URL:

```
    public List<Order> readOrders() throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(OrderConfig.class);

    OrderConfig orderConfig = (OrderConfig) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
            OrderConfigReader.class.getResource(new URL("http://link.here"));
    return orderConfig.getItems();
    }
```

Comment: Javadoc should help: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html

Comment: So there is no other way than to write an if statement? I want to give an url or a filename to the method and get the unmarshalled xml. None of the methods can do that because they have different types.